# Some help removing duplicates in a query without output headers

Tags: google-sheets, duplicates, filtering

So I have about 10,000 lines in some raw data that I want to filter/query onto another tab so I can start analyzing it.  I am trying to do all of this if possible with formulas because the intent here is to automate as much of this as possible.  The best result would be the user just puts in new raw data and all the other tabs just work.  I have done similar things before, but a remove duplicate step is being way more annoying than I hoped.

There is a unique key in the first column that I want to use as my definition of 'unique'.  Unfortunately there is a unix timestamp in column I that I need to keep, but it is NOT the same for the duplicates.  The error is introduced by some bad code owned by the client that we cannot change. It just spits out dupes sometimes and we just have to deal with it.

I am currently removing the duplicates with a query statement that looks like this:

```
select A,min(B),min(C),min(D),min(E),min(F),min(G),min(H),min(I),min(J),min(K) group by A
```

There is also a where clause where I am doing a regex match for a bunch of usernames to verify they are our users, but that is not really part of the issue at this point, just letting you know the query is used for other things, not JUST removing dupes.

The problem is that this introduces a header row in the output with 'min' at the top of everything but column A.  I really don't want that.  This query is wrapped in a sort so it ends up displaying in timestamp order.  This sticks the header row with the 'min' down at the bottom of the data.

This is making it crop up in my other tabs that are using this data.  I would really like this tab to be 'clean' if possible.  Any suggestions?

I have seen that I can do `label min(B) ""` in the query string to get rid of the labels, but I would have to do that for every column making it even more of an unreadable mess.
I am only on this project temporarily and want to make this sheet as maintainable as I can.

In case you need to see the formulas I am actually using, here they are:
query string (the textjoin creates the list of usernames from another tab that I need to filter by):

```
="select A,min(B),min(C),min(D),min(E),min(F),min(G),min(H),min(I),min(J),min(K) where G matches '(" & TEXTJOIN("|",TRUE,'E/E Import'!$L$2:$L) & ")' group by A"
```

query formula:

```
=sort(QUERY('Raw Data'!A:Z,A1),9,TRUE)
```

Is there an all around better way to do this?  Should I just bite the bullet and use the label syntax to get rid of it, or is there a way I can trim the header out in the formula with the sort easily?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=SORT(QUERY(QUERY('Raw Data'!A:Z, A1), "offset 1", 0), 9, 1)
```

Comment: Will that introduce a blank row in the data or not?

Comment: @Alluvian it will remove the min(column) row